Questions about trigonometric substitution integral
When integrate $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$, $x$ could be substituted by $a \sin \theta$, but if not root sign, it is the 2nd power of $(a^2-x^2)$, the 3rd power, etc... like $\dfrac{1}{(a^2 - x^2)^n}$ can it still be substituted by $\sin$? Why?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Not a complete answer
[You certainly can use the substitution $x=a\sin(\theta)$ but the problem becomes so much bigger I wouldn't recommend it. In this case using partial fraction decomposition is for sure an easier/faster way to solve these type of integrals ]
Under $x=a\sin(\theta) \to dx=a\cos(\theta)d\theta$  the integral becomes
$$\int\frac{1}{(a^2-(a\sin(\theta))^2)^n}a\cos(\theta)d\theta=\int\frac{a\cos(\theta)}{(a^2-a^2\sin(\theta)^2)^n}d\theta=\int\frac{a\cos(\theta)}{a^{2n}(1-\sin(\theta))^n}d\theta=\\a^{1-2n}\int\frac{\cos(\theta)}{1-\sin(\theta)^n}d\theta$$
Focus on $\int\frac{\cos(x)}{1-\sin(x)^n}dx$ , for the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ it is equal to $-\log(1-\sin(x))$ and $\tanh^{-1}(\sin(x))$ respectively .
For general $n$ wolfram alpha gives the answer $$\sin(x)  _2\operatorname{F}_1(1,\frac{1}{n};1+\frac{1}{n};\sin(x)^n)+C$$ But I'm still unable to find a step by step way to get there, I will edit my answer when/if I manage to go any further.

Thank you, waiting for you~

The integrand should have reduced to a power of $\cos$

Oh, I check that, you make a mistake, not (1−sin(θ) at the bottom, but (1-sin^2(θ)=cos^2(θ)!!!!
